# KeyError 'pytest' while installing POPPY 0.3

Tags: python, installation, astropy

While using pip to install POPPY 0.3, with all the resources needed, I get several warnings about an Astropy Deprecation Warning and pysynphot things that I don't really understand. On the last few lines before failure, the Traceback shows that the error is in the astropy setup_helpers file. the next line says KeyError 'pytest'. Has anyone experienced this or have any insight on my situation?

This is the command prompt stuff:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\psteffanic>pip install poppy --upgrade
Downloading/unpacking poppy 
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\psteff~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_psteffan
ic\poppy\setup.py) egg_info for package poppy
    WARNING: AstropyDeprecationWarning: ConfigurationItem has been deprecated in
 astropy 0.4. Use ConfigItem objects as members of ConfigNamespace subclasses in
stead.  See ConfigNamespace for an example. [astropy.config.configuration]
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysynphot\locations.py:14: UserWarning: PYSYN_
CDBS is undefined; functionality will be SEVERELY crippled.
      warnings.warn("PYSYN_CDBS is undefined; functionality will be SEVERELY "
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysynphot\locations.py:74: UserWarning: Extinc
tion files should be moved to $PYSYN_CDBS/extinction for compatibility with futu
re versions of pysynphot.
      warnings.warn('Extinction files should be moved to '
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysynphot\locations.py:110: UserWarning: Extin
ction files not found in grid\extinction
      warnings.warn('Extinction files not found in %s' % (extdir,))
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysynphot\locations.py:88: UserWarning: PYSYN_
CDBS is undefined; cannot find mtab\*_tmg.fits file
      warnings.warn("PYSYN_CDBS is undefined; cannot find %s file" % template)
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysynphot\locations.py:88: UserWarning: PYSYN_
CDBS is undefined; cannot find mtab\*_tmc.fits file
      warnings.warn("PYSYN_CDBS is undefined; cannot find %s file" % template)
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysynphot\locations.py:88: UserWarning: PYSYN_
CDBS is undefined; cannot find mtab\*_tmt.fits file
      warnings.warn("PYSYN_CDBS is undefined; cannot find %s file" % template)
   WARNING: AstropyDeprecationWarning: astropy.setup_helpers.update_package_fil
es is deprecated.  Update your setup.py to use astropy.setup_helpers.get_package
_info instead. [astropy.setup_helpers]

Installing collected packages: poppy
  Running setup.py install for poppy
    generating default poppy.cfg file in poppy\poppy.cfg
    WARNING: AstropyDeprecationWarning: ConfigurationItem has been deprecated in
 astropy 0.4. Use ConfigItem objects as members of ConfigNamespace subclasses in
stead.  See ConfigNamespace for an example. [astropy.config.configuration]
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysynphot\locations.py:14: UserWarning: PYSYN_
CDBS is undefined; functionality will be SEVERELY crippled.
      warnings.warn("PYSYN_CDBS is undefined; functionality will be SEVERELY "
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysynphot\locations.py:74: UserWarning: Extinc
tion files should be moved to $PYSYN_CDBS/extinction for compatibility with futu
re versions of pysynphot.
      warnings.warn('Extinction files should be moved to '
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysynphot\locations.py:110: UserWarning: Extin
ction files not found in grid\extinction
      warnings.warn('Extinction files not found in %s' % (extdir,))
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysynphot\locations.py:88: UserWarning: PYSYN_
CDBS is undefined; cannot find mtab\*_tmg.fits file
       warnings.warn("PYSYN_CDBS is undefined; cannot find %s file" % template)
     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysynphot\locations.py:88: UserWarning: PYSYN_
CDBS is undefined; cannot find mtab\*_tmc.fits file
      warnings.warn("PYSYN_CDBS is undefined; cannot find %s file" % template)
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysynphot\locations.py:88: UserWarning: PYSYN_
CDBS     is undefined; cannot find mtab\*_tmt.fits file
      warnings.warn("PYSYN_CDBS is undefined; cannot find %s file" % template)
    WARNING: AstropyDeprecationWarning: astropy.setup_helpers.update_package_fil
es is deprecated.  Update your setup.py to use astropy.setup_helpers.get_package
_info instead. [astropy.setup_helpers]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\psteff~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_psteffanic\poppy\setu
p.py", line 144, in <module>
        use_2to3=False
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.32-py2.7.egg\setuptools
\command\install.py", line 53, in run
        return _install.run(self)
       File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\astropy-0.4-py2.7-win32.egg\astropy\se
tup_helpers.py", line 623, in run
        for k, (fnsrc, v) in six.iteritems(self.distribution.command_options['py
test']):
    KeyError: 'pytest'
   Record file c:\users\psteff~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-lze5cj-record\install-rec
 ord.txt not found
Successfully installed poppy 
Cleaning up...

C:\Users\psteffanic>
```

Comment: Was able to duplicate this on Windows7 running cygwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a combination of a couple things:

1) It looks like a possible small bug in the Astropy build code that poppy is using.

2) It looks like poppy is not yet fully compatible with the latest version of Astropy (v0.4) so in the meantime you might try downgrading to Astropy v0.3.2 if nothing else.

Meanwhile you should contact the authors of the package about issues like this.